# gvim 7.3 on Windows 7: netrw ftp unable to browse remote directory, obtain files

Tags: vim, ftp, netrw

I'm using gvim 7.3 on Windows 7 to try access a parent folder on a remote site using netrw ftp.

I've entered the following command in gvim:

```
:e ftp://hostname/path/to/dir
```

Following the prompt for my login details this error message flashes past:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\path\to\Vim\vimfiles 
\view\ftp=-=+ftp.adddress_to=+my_parent_folder=+-:
line 101:
E303: Unable to open swap file for "ftp:\\ftp.address_to\my_parent_dir\", recovery    
impossible
```

The subdirectory and files of the parent directory are then displayed in the vim netrw window.

But on trying to open any of these subdirectories (with the cursor over the name and pressing the return key) nothing appears to happen - the display of same parent directory remains on the screen. The only visible change to the screen is that the filepath listed at the top of the netrw window changes to point the directory that I selected.

When trying to obtain a file I get the message:

```
**error** (netrw) Can't change directory to directory_name/: No such file or directory
```

NB: My vimrc 'set nocompatible' and 'filetype plugin on' are present.

Any help appreciated.

GilF

Comment: It looks like you are starting Vim from a protected directory. Start it from your `$HOME` or another writable directory.

Comment: hello romainl, thank you for helping me. apologies for the delay in replying.  GilF